# Difficult to pick the Date of Birth from Primefaces Calender?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF application where the Date of Birth is recorded from PrimeFaces Calender. When entering the Date of Birth, Navigation involves clicking the buttons 12 times a year. It is practically difficult to add birthdays in 1970's. Entering plain text is not preferred by the user? Any other option to pick the date of several years back from a UI controller easier than that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mark navigator as true and give a yearRange for the navigator.

```
<p:calendar yearRange="c-100:c" navigator="true"  />
```

This allows to record data of birth of people up to 100 years old. Will not be able to pick date in future.

Answer (score 1):

With the primefaces calendar, you can use `navigator="true"`, so you can select the year from a dropdown:

```
<p:calendar id="cal" value="#{your property}" navigator="true" display="inline"/>
```